# Why is my code not indenting correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation

I am having some trouble with my [Python 3.6] code. I'm not sure whats wrong, and I have tried many ways to fix it but none work.

The problem is at the line where it says "Class Mainarchive:", I think its an indenting error

```
import time
print("Welcome to Code Vault Abraxis")
time.sleep(1)

class Username:
  print()
  username1 = input("Username: ")
  username2 = ("AbraxisUser")

  while username1 != username2:
    time.sleep(1)
    print()
    username1 = input("Username does not exist. Username: ")

class Password:
  time.sleep(1)
  print()
  password1 = input("Password:  ")
  password2 = ("cats")

  while password1 != password2:
   time.sleep(1)
   print()
   password1 = input("Wrong Password! Try again. Password: ")
```

This is where the problem is

```
class Mainarchive:
  def secrets(sec):
  time.sleep(2)
    print("1.")
    print("2.")
    print("3.")
    print("4.")
    print("5.")
def projects(pro):
time.sleep(2)
  print("1.")
  print("2.")
  print("3.")
  print("4.")
  print("5.")
```

continued from class mainarchive

```
  block1 = input()
  while block1 == ("a")
    print("Stored Data is shown below.")
    return sec
    time.sleep(1)
    secrets()
   while block1 == ("b")
    print("Stored Data is shown below.")
    return pro
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What's the exact error with full stack trace? And is this the *exact* code? There are some pretty obvious indentation errors, like `time.sleep(2)` being at the same indentation as `def secrets(sec):`

Comment: don't you need a : at the end of a while line? while block1 == ("a") and while block1 == ("b")?

Answer (score 0):

You have indentation errors at both the `time.sleep(2)` as well as `while block1 == ("b")` and `while block1 == ("a")` are missing a semicolon at the end and `while block1 == ("b")` is not indented properly.

Here is the corrected code:

```
import time
print("Welcome to Code Vault Abraxis")
time.sleep(1)

class Username:
  print()
  username1 = input("Username: ")
  username2 = ("AbraxisUser")

  while username1 != username2:
    time.sleep(1)
    print()
    username1 = input("Username does not exist. Username: ")

class Password:
  time.sleep(1)
  print()
  password1 = input("Password:  ")
  password2 = ("cats")

  while password1 != password2:
   time.sleep(1)
   print()
   password1 = input("Wrong Password! Try again. Password: ")

class Mainarchive:
  def secrets(sec):
    time.sleep(2)
    print("1.")
    print("2.")
    print("3.")
    print("4.")
    print("5.")
def projects(pro):
  time.sleep(2)
  print("1.")
  print("2.")
  print("3.")
  print("4.")
  print("5.")

  block1 = input()
  while block1 == "a":
    print("Stored Data is shown below.")
    return sec
    time.sleep(1)
    secrets()
  while block1 == "b":
    print("Stored Data is shown below.")
    return pro
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while password1 != password2:
 time.sleep(1)
 print()
 password1 = input("Wrong Password! Try again. Password: ")
```

and here:

```
   while block1 == ("b")
    print("Stored Data is shown below.")
    return pro
    time.sleep(1)
```

you have only one space, all other lines has 2 space indentation.